# Win10 install beside Ubuntu 16.04 + SecureBoot

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, windows-10, secure-boot, boot-partition

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in my machine about 4 months ago.
Some days ago I changed the partition system from MBR to GPT and the boot mechanism to UEFI. Without data loss or reinstall the existing OS.
Now I consider to install Win10 beside my Ubuntu with SecureBoot if possible.

My questions is:

1. Can I change the boot of my existing Ubuntu to SecureBoot?
   (to I must not to switch of it in Windows, after its installation)
   (reinstall Ubuntu is not an option of course)

   Maybe need to change the boot loader to shim?
   (or it is not such a simple task?)
2. Can I install Win10 in my existing EFI partition?
   (there is another trouble to can fall in?)

If someone can point me to an existing step by step instructions for these, it would be helpfull. I sent 2-3 hours to find it but allways the first installed OS is Windows and Ubuntu is the second (with SecureBoot at installation). I guess it is a reliable order, but I want it oposite :-).

Regards,
Imre

Comment: Secure boot is a property of your bios (UEFI) and in theory you should be able to enable secure boot. If you have problems booting / running ubuntu with secure boot you would have to either disable it or sign the kernel modules you need, your choice. https://insights.ubuntu.com/2017/08/11/how-to-sign-things-for-secure-boot/ . Personally I consider signing kernel modules rather trivial, but others can not be bothered and so disable secure boot, up to you to decide.

Comment: As far as windows goes, you should be fine, but if you have questions or problems ask on a windows support channel. You may need to restore grub post install .

Comment: Ubuntu supports secure boot. you should be able to turn it on and boot just fine. Windows can use the same EFI partition without issue. There is one possible problem with Installing Windows 10, Many people have had issue with Win10 Creators' update deleting linux partitions. I do not know if the installer will present the same problem.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We’re sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Comment: See also:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/852005/is-re-enabling-secure-boot-in-uefi-secure

Comment: After you someone ask me to split it, so it is in processing.

Yes, I know the BIOS settings and when you set it to an UEFI booted Ubuntu, it will not start. Need to set something in it.
Maybe change the boot loader to an PK signed one (shim) or other.

Comment: One is done, you can delete this question because someone warning me to ask the same.

Comment: Finished to split two question, please delete this.

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu in legacy mode ?

Comment: Yes, MBR -> GPT and UEFI boot was manually managed.
Windows 10 installer did not want to run in an UEFI machine, so I have manage this conversion. I can give up secure boot, but consider of it.

Comment: I do not understand your last comment. What does "GPT and UEFI boot was manually managed" mean ? " Windows 10 installer did not want to run in an UEFI machine, so I have manage this conversion" what ? I do not understand how you are booting windows, UEFI or legacy ? "I can give up secure boot, but consider of it." ??? Both Windows and Ubuntu should be installed with UEFI (not legacy boot). Enable secure boot and see what happens (which is what I asked you long ago).

Comment: 1. If you boot MBR mode with linux it does not matter what is in the BIOS ("Windows" or "Other OS") in Boot->security, OK?

2. After change your Partitions to GPT, Ubuntu to UEFI boot and change the BIOS boot security to "Windows" you will receive a nice message that "Your system is under unathorized changes ...". OK?

3. If you want to install Win 10 from USB pendrive and your HDD in MBR partitioned, you will receive also a nice message that is not want to install onto HDD, OK?
So you have to make the changes in point 2.
I would not waste your time if it was not experience.