# Change Ubuntu 16.04 secure boot after installation

Tags: secure-boot

Can I change an existing Ubuntu 16.04 to boot with SecureBoot (motherboard BIOS - UEFI) settings beside a Windows 10?
It was installed without this and now is grub-efi the boot loader.

Comment: You asked the same question here - https://askubuntu.com/questions/991901/win10-install-beside-ubuntu-16-04-secureboot and I answered in the comments. Enable secure boot in your BIOS and post if you have a problem.